# SSRS Multiple DataSets in Tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have 2 tablix that are using different datasets. I have a third table that need to do calculation based on those 2 tablix result sets.Please find the attached sample report tablix[image: Attached report tablix example].[image: Second table]

In the third table,I have to find total amount of one of the row from first table/Avg(second table revenue field). This EOM has 3 date values. These 2 table does not have relationship with each other. Could anyone please suggest how to use lookup function here to combine the dataset? TIA

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bit of custom code to create a report-level variable that can be set in one table/tablix and referenced in a different one. Take a look at this link, which has some basic code provided:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/883a94f3-0c1e-4a98-b32a-ac58d55a71d9/definedeclare-a-variable-in-sql-reporting-services?forum=sqlreportingservices